# How to disable file system access (by UNC) to the document library in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, unc, event-receiver

I created the document library in SharePoint 2010.
I can access the document library through UNC path like \server\sitecollection\path, e.g. \domain.com\applications\libraryName
Is there any way disable file system access (by UNC) to the document library in SharePoint 2010 ?

Indirect problem is that the Event Receiver doesn't fire when adding document to the library through file system access (e.g. Windows Explorer). 
I assume that Event Receiver's are based on web events. Am I right ?

Comment: No, Event receiver fire on Web DAV _updates_ as well as on API udpates: `SPListItem item; item.Update();` in any console application or timer job. There has to be another issue with your event receiver.